# Matching paragraphs with regex

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

Can somebody explain me why the following text:

```
<p>some text some text...</p>
<p>another text another <b>text</b>again</p>
```

can't be parsed with the following regular expression:

```
<p>.*?</p>
```

(to retrieve every paragraph).
The regular expression that should match the text between the first opening <p> tag and the last closing </p> tag doesn't work either:

```
<p>.*</p>
```

Comment: Wow look someone is parsing HTML with Regex! (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: "Doesn't work" is almost *never* an appropriate level of diagnostics. What does it do, compared with what you *want* it to do?

Comment: 2Jon Skeet: well - "no matches are found"

Comment: Could you post some code sample of how you retrieve the match?

Comment: have you tested your regex on other platforms, like an online regex tester?

Comment: I feel that if I had to pick one take away from SO, it's that you shouldn't parse HTML with Regex, as it is not a regular language.

Comment: It could be XML or SGML... admittedly it's probably HTML and might be better served with a state machine but if it's just extracting paragraph info the the HTML aspect shouldn't be of concern. @Serge, how is it failing? Can you show the code you are using this Regex within.

Comment: 2Lazarus: The code is simple:
var matches = Regex.Matches(inputText, regexPattern, options);
The arguments are provided from the UI. Some other simple regexs are matched just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the fact that it's dangerous to parse (X)HTMl with regex, try with the `RegexOptions.Singleline`

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that you are attempting a multi line match without telling the regex engine to do so.  Take a look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk1x0726.aspx) doc for passing in the flag.

Comment: I tried both - with and without the RegexOptions.Multiline option: neither works

Answer (score 1):

[You can't parse HTML with RegEx.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)